# jQuery index() - multilevel <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing

I was wondering if it was possible to get the index of a single `<li>` in a multilevel `<ul>`...

Let's say I have the following unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>
        2
        <ul>
            <li>2.1</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li id="position">4</li>
</ul>
```

When I use `$('#position').index();` It returns 3 (zero based, 4th element), but I want it to return 5; since it's the 6th `<li>` in the `<ul>`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting the context of the index to all the li's in the ul :

```
$('#position').index('ul li');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kB2vD/)

or even the other way around:

```
$('ul li').index($('#position'));
```

or specific to this UL only:

```
$('#position').closest('ul').find('li').index($('#position'));
```

Comment: Oh wow, I never knew it would be this easy! I noticed that you could give a parameter to the index function but I just didn't quite get it... Thanks for the fast answer!